# How to get data from nested array in DataTables?

Tags: datatables

I used to download data from a json file in this format to my DataTables table:

```
{
    "data": [
        ["n/a","668","01.11.2021 14:16:20", ... ],
        ["n/a","670","05.11.2021 23:23:54", ...]
    ]
}

...
        "ajax": "first.json",
        columns: [ 
            { data: 0 },
            { data: 1 }
...
```

And everythig was ok

But now format of my json was changed:

```
{
    "data": {
        "deals": [["n/a", "718", "30/11/2021 21:46:14"], ["", "718", "30/11/2021 21:46:14"], ... ], 
        "stops": [["07/10/2021 21:48:28", "BTCUSDT"], ["07/10/2021 21:48:28", "BTCUSDT"], ... ] 
    }
}
```

And I try to get data like this and get "No data available in table":

```
...
        "ajax": "first.json",
        columns: [ 
            { data: 'deals.0' },
            { data: 'deals.1' }
...
```

How can I get data from new format of json to my table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your new JSON structure, provided by the URL:

```js
{
    "data": {
        "deals": [
            ["n/a", "718", "30/11/2021 21:46:14"],
            ["", "718", "30/11/2021 21:46:14"]
        ],
        "stops": [
            ["07/10/2021 21:48:28", "BTCUSDT"],
            ["07/10/2021 21:48:28", "BTCUSDT"]
        ]
    }
}
```

In this structure, the location of the deals data is `data.deals`.  This location points to an array of arrays, which is what DataTables needs (or an array of objects).

(This means the table will only have access to the `deals` data, since the `stops` data is in a separate location entirely. But I will assume you only want the `deals` data to match your original example.)

You therefore need to use the DataTables [`dataSrc`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) option to tell DataTables where to look in your new JSON:

```html
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%"></table>
```

and:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#example').DataTable( {
    ajax: {
      method: "GET",
      url: "first.json", // or whatever URL you want to use
      dataSrc: "data.deals"
    },
    "columns": [
      { "title": "Col 1" },
      { "title": "Col 2" },
      { "title": "Col 3" }
    ]
            
  } );

} );
```

Because each row of data is an array, you don't need to specify the specific array indexes in your `columns` - DataTables will iterate over each row array for you.

The result is:

[image]